# How to access HiddenField value in dropdownlist onchange event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

How do i access  gridview itemtemplate hiddenfield value from the dropdownlist onchange event?. Basically if you see below i'm calling ConfirmStatus on dropdownlist value change and i need to pass hiddenfield value to that method.

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText="Status" >
  <ItemTemplate>

   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransactionList"  Visible = "False" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTransactionList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
       onchange=" if(ConfirmStatus(this)!=1){ return false;}"
                              runat="server"/>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus"  Visible="True" Text='<%# ShowStatus( Container.DataItem ) %>' />
   <input id="hiddenOriginalStatus" type="hidden" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I don't see you assigning any value to you hidden field `hiddenOriginalStatus` from the above code, from where does it gets assigned?

Comment: @YanBrunet   Tried to access the hidden field value in the jquery function using this but with no results alert($(this).parent.find('#hiddenOriginalStatus"').val());

Comment: Since it's an ID you don't need to go through the parent and all. Just go `$('#hiddenOriginalStatus').val()`.

Comment: @YanBrunet Will this give me  hiidenfield value of the row where dropdownlist event is triggered

Comment: @YanBrunet Tried this it is giving me undefined function ConfirmStatus(ddl) {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to update the status?");
        
        var control = 'MainContent_BelowMenuContent_TransactionGrid_inpHide';
        if (x == true) {
            document.getElementById(control).value = true;
            return 1;
        } else {
            alert($('#hiddenOriginalStatus').val());
            (ddl).val("PENDING");
            document.getElementById(control).value = false;
            return 0;
        }

    }

Comment: In which event do you assign value for `hiddenOriginalStatus`?. Any reason why don't you trigger the `onchange` from the code behind?

Comment: @YanBrunet Basically i'm letting user confirm if he wants to go and confirm the dropdownlist change and if he doesnot want to then need to reset the dropdown with initial value. Trigger onchange from code behind i'm not sure how to do that.Appreciate your help

Comment: If you have multiple elements using the same ID, you could run into problems. I would suggest you to give it a class so that you could find it easily as a sibling of your current ddl. `$(ddl).sibblings('.OriginalStatus').val()` this would work even if you have multiple instance of these controls (like in a repeater of some sort).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather trigger the `onchange` from the code behind because that's where you assign and have all the value for.

```
 protected void gridview1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
          HiddenField hiddenOriginalStatus = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hiddenOriginalStatus");
          (e.Row.FindControl("ddlTransactionList") as DropDownList).Attributes.Add("onchange", "ConfirmStatus('" + hiddenOriginalStatus.Value + "');");
      }
 }
```